# What is a word for the concept of maintaining uncertainty in your enemies?

Tags: word-choice

Specifically by introducing bad data over time to limit their ability to deduce things? Not necessarily warfare-related. I'm thinking "information warfare," "instilling doubt," or "sabotage," but none of these seem specific enough. I'm looking for a word that means *just* that.

Comment: You know, a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/mislead) is a wonderful thing.  ("Beguile" and "belie" would appear to be two good candidates.)

Comment: The term [misdirection](https://www.google.it/search?q=misdirection&oq=misdirection&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=misdirection+definition) has its uses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is [***disinformation***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation).

> “In espionage or military intelligence, *disinformation* is the deliberate spreading of false information to mislead an enemy as to one's position or course of action.”

Comment: I would appreciate a less militarized synonym, but understand that that's probably what I'm looking for.

Comment: I believe you will find the linked article helpful -- the term is not specific to military contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **deception**

> Definition: those measures designed to mislead the enemy by
>   manipulation, distortion, or falsification of evidence to induce the
>   enemy to react in a manner prejudicial to the enemy's interests.

*Russian military deception, sometimes known as Maskirovka (Маскировка = masking) is a military doctrine developed from the start of the 20th century. Deceptive measures include concealment, manoeuvres intended to deceive, denial and disinformation*.